# Android Parcelable - read/write data to Parcel using generic data type

Tags: java, android, arraylist, set, parcelable

How can i implement to write my `Set < ArrayList < ? > >` to my Parcel using generic data type ?

Here is my code..

```
        dest.writeList(getArrTRA());
        dest.writeList(getArrTSAC());
        dest.write???(getArrListSet()); //how can i write my Set<ArrayList<?


public Set<ArrayList<?>> getArrListSet() {
        return arrSetOfPaymentMode;
    }
```

Comment: try `dest.writeList(new ArrayList<>(getArrListSet()));`

Comment: its not working if i create new instance of arraylist.. what if i cast it to an arraylist?

Comment: what is the method defintion for `getArrListSet()`

Comment: what is the datatype of arrSetOfPaymentMode?

Comment: hello there.. the data type of arrSetOfPaymentMode is Set<ArrayList<?>> its arraylist is generic object.. how can i implement it when using an generic object? i wan to implement read and write to my parcel how can i do that..?

Comment: Wow this tool is Great. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ImageContainer implements Serializable, Parcelable  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ImageContainer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public ImageContainer(Parcel in) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    readFromParcel(in);
}


/**
 * custom images in this article
 */
@SerializedName("Image")
ArrayList<ImageCls> alCustomImages=new ArrayList<ImageCls>();

public ArrayList<ImageCls> getAlCustomImages() {
    return alCustomImages;
}
public void setAlCustomImages(ArrayList<ImageCls> alCustomImages) {
    this.alCustomImages = alCustomImages;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeList(alCustomImages);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.alCustomImages = in.readArrayList(ImageCls.class.getClassLoader());
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public ImageContainer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ImageContainer(in);
    }

    public ImageContainer[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ImageContainer[size];
    }
};
}
```

your class should implement Parcelable. An example is in above code.

> **Your issue is you are trying to read/write generic data type to the Parcel. But it is not possible to read/write generic data type in parcel. Read more how to use Parcelable [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)  and Parcel [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)**

Comment: how can i read and write generic data type Set<ArrayList<?>> for my Parcelable..?

Comment: it is not possible to read/write generic data type in parcel. read more how to use Parcelable here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html and Parcel here developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

Comment: Thanks man! i've wasted my time debugging it for a nothing haha!