# How to pass ArrayList of Custom objects to new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

I have created the class textViewTable In this class i am saving data related to TextViews That I want to Pass to Next Activity.

```
public class TextViewTable implements Serializable {
private String FONT;
private String TEXT;
private float TEXT_SIZE;
private ColorStateList TEXT_COLOR;
private float MARGIN_TOP;
private float MARGIN_BOTTOM;
private float MARGIN_LEFT;
private float MARGIN_RIGHT;
private Boolean BoldFlag;
private Boolean ItalicFlag;
private Boolean NormalFlag;

public TextViewTable(){
}

public TextViewTable(String FONT, String TEXT, float TEXT_SIZE, ColorStateList TEXT_COLOR, float MARGIN_TOP, float MARGIN_BOTTOM, float MARGIN_LEFT, float MARGIN_RIGHT, Boolean boldFlag, Boolean italicFlag, Boolean normalFlag) {
    this.FONT = FONT;
    this.TEXT = TEXT;
    this.TEXT_SIZE = TEXT_SIZE;
    this.TEXT_COLOR = TEXT_COLOR;
    this.MARGIN_TOP = MARGIN_TOP;
    this.MARGIN_BOTTOM = MARGIN_BOTTOM;
    this.MARGIN_LEFT = MARGIN_LEFT;
    this.MARGIN_RIGHT = MARGIN_RIGHT;
    BoldFlag = boldFlag;
    ItalicFlag = italicFlag;
    NormalFlag = normalFlag;
}
```

}

From my activit i want to send ArrayList of Objects of TextViewTable class.
I have use the below function to send the ArrayList. But every time I am getting null pointer exception. Please Help to solve this.

```
public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), displayImage.class);            
        Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
        bundleObject.putSerializable("key", textViewsData);

        intent.putExtras(bundleObject);
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
};
```

[image: LogCat]

Comment: You need to find where the pointer is null, and then why it is null. See: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: just read your stacktrace : Caused by NotSerializableException ...

Comment: use some singleton class set list in one activity and read it in other activity. This will make task more easy

Answer (score 1):

Currently using `Bundle.putSerializable` for sending `TextViewTable` class object `ArrayList` to next Activity but not implementing `Serializable` interface in `TextViewTable` class:

```
public class TextViewTable implement Serializable{

 ....
}
```

Comment: its not working ... null pointer exception on this line startActivity(intent)

Comment: @NighterZ: Please share logcat stace

Comment: null pointer exception resolved..now I am getting this exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object...wait I post logcat stace

Comment: @NighterZ: please share exception

Comment: null pointer exception was due to some other reason, that piece of code is not in the post. and i am sorry  I don't how to post logcat stace so I post the screen shot of the logcat.

Comment: hmm .. it complains about ColorStateList but according to developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html it should implement Parcelable

Comment: @cYrixmorten your right problem is with ColorStateList. I am still trying to solve it. If you know some solution then please tell me.

Comment: @NighterZ I would either simply store a static reference to TextViewTable in another class, which then can be fetched by the second activity, or use EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. Then you can do something like `EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(yourTextViewTable)` => start second activity => in onCreate() `TextViewTable table = EventBus.getDefault().getSticky(TextViewTable.class)`

Answer (score 1):

you can follow ρяσѕρєя K's answer OR also you can do like below code:

```
public class GeneralClass{

  public static ArrayList<TextViewTable> data = new ArrayList<TextViewTable>();

}
```

and then you can store your data in above arraylist on first activity like below:

```
Collections.copy(GeneralClass.data,textViewsData);
```

and now you can use GeneralClass.data arraylist in your second activity;

Comment: Either this or EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Sending the `POJO`  from one activity  to  another acitivity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ArrayList<StatusData> passData = new ArrayList<StatusData>();
bundle.putSerializable("key", passData);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
//then the transaction part
```

Getting the bundle`:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   ArrayList<StatusData> dataReceived = (ArrayList<StatusData>)bundle.getSerializable("key"));
```

and then do whatever you like.Hope this helps.Cheers.
You can also use [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Answer (score 0):

First Activity

```
public void shareCustomArrayListObject(ArrayList<CUSTOMOBJECT> arrayList) {
    if (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() > 0) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), displayImage.class);            
         Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
         bundle.putSerializable("KEY", arrayList);

         intent.putExtras(bundleObject);
    }
}
```

Second activity where you want to retrieve the arraylist

```
 private ArrayList<CUSTOMOBJECT> arrayList;

    Bundle bundle=YOURACTIVITY.getBundle();

    if(bundle==null){
        bundle=getArguments();
    }

    if(bundle.getSerializable("KEY")!=null){
    arrayList=(ArrayList)bundle.getSerializable("KEY");
    }
```

and also if you have made a bean class for the arraylist 
you need to implement

```
public class CUSTOMOBJECT implements Serializable{
```

and you done :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28871200/1576416) object to pass data between activities as below:

Passing data from activity A to activity B

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", array_list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Getting data in Activity B from activity A

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
array_list = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

So simple.

I hope this will help you.