# Unable to Pass an ArrayList of JSONObjects to new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

I am having trouble passing an `ArrayList<JSONObject>` to a new activity.

In my Search activity I use

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", resultsArray);
```

But I get a `Wrong Argument error`.

I used this SO question as a reference.
[Intent.putExtra List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543811/intent-putextra-list)

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<JSONObject> resultsArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //other stuff
        resultsArray = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    }


    public void goToActivity(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchResultsListActivity.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", resultsArray);
            startActivity(intent);
    }

    // ...

}
```

My **SearchResultsListAcivity** is just a list

```
public class SearchResultsListAcivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<JSONObject> searchResultsArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // .. .

        searchResultsArray = getStringArrayListExtra("data");

        ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<JSONObject>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, searchResultsArray);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResults);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I also have toyed with the implmentation answer listed here [How to pass ArrayList of Custom objects to new activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554405/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-custom-objects-to-new-activity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), displayImage.class);            
Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
bundleObject.putSerializable("KEY", arrayList);
intent.putExtras(bundleObject);
```

But again I get wrong argument error.

Comment: `JSONObject` does not implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.  You'll have to pass it as a `String[]` or something and manage serialization and deserialization yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just transform your JSON array into a String array and then pass that to your next activity using `putStringArrayListExtra()`. You can decode it back to JSON array in your `SearchResultsListActivity` activity.

i) Transform your JSON array (or list) into a String array

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).toString());}
```

ii) Pass it to your `SearchResultsListActivity` activity as extra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchResultsListActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("string_array", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

iii) Finally decode it in your next activity

```
Bundle stringArrayList = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> list = stringArrayList.getStringArrayList("string_array");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(list);
```

I have not tried this code but at least it should give you an idea on how to solve your problem. You might have to make minor changes (the last line maybe replace it for a for loop if it doesn't work, etc)