# How to writeToParcel an ArrayList of interface

Tags: android, interface, parcelable

There is an interface `DrawingElement` (extending `Parcelable`) with multiple implementations. There is a field `List<DrawingElement> elements` in another class, which implements `Parcelable`. So the List should be written to the Parcel, but the method for reading Parcelable ArrayList requires a concrete class for referencing the concrete implementation of a Creator and this is not working: `in.createTypedArrayList(DrawingElement.CREATOR)`.

```
public interface DrawingElement extends Parcelable {
}

public class FirstDrawingElementImpl implements DrawingElement {
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // done easily.
    }
}

public class SecondDrawingElementImpl implements DrawingElement {
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // done easily.
    }
}

public class DrawingElementsContainer implements Parcelable {
    private List<DrawingElement> elements;

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

If I had to use the @pskink suggestion, I had to do weird casting like:

```
protected Drawing(Parcel in) {
    DrawingElement[] parcelables = (DrawingElement[]) in.readParcelableArray(DrawingElement.class.getClassLoader());
    elements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parcelables));
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelableArray(elements.toArray(new Parcelable[elements.size()]), flags);
}
```

`dest.writeList(elements)` is the obvious decision, but I got confused by passing an interface classloader.

Comment: would help to see how you're implementing it

Comment: what do you need that `Parcelable` for?

Comment: @ootinii, if I knew how to implement writing a List of interfaces to a Parcel, there would be no question at all.

Comment: @pskink, I need it in the onSaveInstanceState method.

Comment: interface is a "code", you need to save some "state": which is your data, not code

Comment: @pskink, you have a better way of working with data in Android than using code?

Comment: ok so you want to write the `Parcelable` object and not some "abstract interface", then use `writeParcelableArray` / `readParcelableArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to define your class. `parcel.readArrayList` method is used to read the list from the parcel and `parcel.wrtieList` method is used to write list to the parcel. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28871200/1576416).

```
public class DrawingElementsContainer implements Parcelable {

    private ArrayList<DrawingElement> elements;

    public DrawingElementsContainer(Parcel in) {
        elements=in.readArrayList(DrawingElement.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public ArrayList<DrawingElement> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(ArrayList<DrawingElement> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public DrawingElementsContainer()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(elements);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DrawingElementsContainer> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<DrawingElementsContainer>() {
        public DrawingElementsContainer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DrawingElementsContainer(in);
        }

        public DrawingElementsContainer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DrawingElementsContainer[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Hope it might help you

Comment: Can you please give any explanation on how the interface class loader works for resolving an implementation class. This is what confused me.

Comment: you can class instead of interface (for DrawingElement) here to make it work for you. is it necessary for you to use interface only?

Comment: Yes, I do, this is the point of the question. The interesting part is that your code actually works. Some magic happens in the background, that I don't fully comprehend.

Comment: Its not a magic. It is the way of implementation. It works based on our implementations